# Rewrite domain, but still use index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Current code to use index.php for all urls :

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php`

But for one special case, I want to make url

`http://domain.com/s/this_changes` to call actually
`http://domain.com/steps/step/this_changes`.

I tried adding :

`RewriteRule ^./s/$ ./steps/step/$1`, but it gives an error `500`.

Comment: I wrote you an answer below.

Comment: It is giving you an error because $1 calls brackets in the first part of the code and you have not declared anything in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^s/(.+)$ /steps/step/$1 [L]
```

Another way you could do it is to route all your URIs through index.php, and create a function for each one.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On  

RewriteRule ^s/$ /steps/step/$1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php`
doesn't work, or it isn't supposed to work?

Comment: this would not work, you need to put something in brackets in the first section () in order to use $1 in the second section

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^s/this_changes$ steps/step/this_changes
```

if it is that simple or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ steps/$1/$2
```

And your specific code would work like this

```
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)/?$ ./steps/step/$1
```

The (.*) is referenced in your $1 in the second part of your code.